# while loop condition is not stopping when it's supposed to

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm working on an assignment that adds up all the even number between 2 user inputs. Example; userNum1 = 3, userNum2 = 12. The two numbers are also included in the addition (only if even).
I've gone over my while loop condition for an hour and can't seem to figure out why it's not stopping when the number number being added hit's the user's second number (in this case, 12).

Here's my code.

```
int evenCount = 0;
int evenSum = 0;
int oddNumberFixer = 0;
int evenAddNumber = 0;

while (evenAddNumber <= num2 || evenCount < num2)
    {   
        oddNumberFixer = num1 + 1;

        if ((num1 % 2) != 0)
        {

            evenAddNumber = oddNumberFixer + evenCount;

            evenSum = evenAddNumber + evenSum;
            evenCount = evenCount + 2;



        }
        else 
        {
            evenAddNumber = num1 + evenCount;
            evenSum = evenAddNumber + evenSum;
            evenCount = evenCount + 2;

        }

    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the included evens is " + evenSum);
```

Comment: Don't just stare at your code, step through it line-by-line with the debugger.  This will allow you to inspect the values of variables as it progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about what your algorithm needs to do. Notice that you're increasing evenSum whether or not your number is even. Also, you only need to check if a number is even once. It may seem obvious, but once you know a number is even, adding 2 will always give you another even number. The algorithm could be much simpler if you took more time to think about it before starting to code.

You might try making sure the number is even before beginning a loop. Then you might try

```
for(int i = yourEvenNumber; i <= num2; i+=2) {
    //add them up here    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using a while loop, this seems like a for loop type application.  If you did some initialization ensuring the first number is the first even number you want to add, you can step through 2 at a time, i.e.:

```
int first = num1;

if(first % 2 == 1)
    first++;

for(int i = first; i <= num2; i += 2)
{
    //summing code
}
```

As for your while loop, I suspect it's because the OR statement in your conditional is allowing the loop to continue until evencount >= num2.  This guarantees the loop will continue for 1/2 * num2 iterations.  In you example (3,12), you expect the loop to iterate 5 times (4+6+8+12), but with the second part of your while loop conditional, it will iterate 6 times (evencount = 0,2,4,6,8,10).